# Modal Extender Ajax Control Toolkit (ASP 2.0) will not pop-up on server side trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I tried to create a modal using ajax control toolkit in my sharepoint services services 3.0 project but the pop up will not show when called in server-side.

**//Register Toolkit**

```
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="maku"
Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.20229.20821, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>
```

**Ascx (Where the extender resides)**

```
<maku:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup"
        OnClick="btnPopup_Click"/>
    <maku:modalpopupextender id="mp1" runat="server" popupcontrolid="PopupCommentPanel" 
        cancelcontrolid="btnClose" backgroundcssclass="modalBackground"
        targetcontrolid="btnShow">
    </maku:modalpopupextender>
    <asp:Panel ID="PopupCommentPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" 
        Height="223px" Width="684px" style="display:none">
        SWIMMING SWIMMING SWIMMING
    </asp:Panel>
```

Already set `mp1` (target control) to css style `display:none` (where many issues were caused by this). 
I dont know why the popup will not show.

**Here's the server side code :**

```
//Declaration
protected ModalPopupExtender mp1 = null;

// Page Load
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // Some code here
   mp1.Show(); // Popup will not show
}

//Also added onclick event for target control id 

protected void btnPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mp1.Show(); // Popup will also not showing
}
```

Also added the required dll file in assembly folder :

```
AjaxControlToolkit.dll(1.0.20229.20821)
System.Web.Extensions.dll(1.0.61025.0)
```

In my web.config, I already added the ff:

**//Safe Controls**

```
<SafeControl Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.20229.20821, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" 
  Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

**//Assembly Section**

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.20229.20821, Culture=neutral, 
       PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, 
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

**//Controls**

```
<add tagPrefix="maku" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, 
 Version=1.0.20229.20821, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
```

I didn't encountered any errors bdway.

Comment: Something is completly wrong. Ajax popup on server? You need to use Javascript.

Comment: @Amit please read ajax control toolkit first

Comment: Ok. Kindly point me to read.

Comment: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/ start from here

Comment: @maku `protected ModalPopupExtender mp1 = null;` instead of that, try to declare the control in client side (set a `BehaviourID`) and then invoke the `show()` from server site with button click using that `BehaviourID`.

Comment: @aspiring i did that because the controls that will be used in server side must be declared in our project, classic asp maybe

Comment: I have started from where you said. Landed in Tutorials and ModalPopup extender. There it says `Show` is client side method. You are using it serverside. https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ModalPopup%20Control&referringTitle=Tutorials

Comment: @maku Then you have to use a function in server side to [inject the html script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx) that defines the client side control e.g. `ModalPopupExtender`. That way you can still set the `BehaviourID` and utilize it. I am not in front of a PC with ajax installed to try it, but please give it a try.

Comment: @Amit thanks for reading, i tried this one already and its working from my end, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/215040/ModalPopupExtender-from-Server-Side-Code so no question about that

Comment: @aspiring i tried also registering a script on click of the target control button `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "launchModal();", true);` but with no luck